# What are some good pointers to build a text analysis software?

Tags: text, analysis

Is there a way to check for sentiments in the text?  I am trying to build a chat client which should analyse the text and able to determine the mood of the user

Answer (score 0):

You can try using classification, such as described in the data mining scientific field. You can for example train a support-vector machine (SVM) and use that for classification. Here are two papers I found using this approach on blog text:

- [Understanding how bloggers feel: recognizing affect in blog posts](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1125646)
- [A Hybrid Mood Classification Approach for Blog Text](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-36668-3_141)

And here is a classification approach using features known from psychology which doesn't require training of a model:

- [Mood sensing from social media texts and its applications](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10115-013-0628-8)